# How to set Checkbox value into a array android

Tags: java, android, arrays, checkbox, arraylist

I got an `ArrayList`:

`ArrayList<CheckBox> swmsInfo = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();`

and some checkboxes:

```
checkBoxCompany = createCheckBox(R.id.checkBoxCompany);

checkBoxName = createCheckBox(R.id.checkBoxName);
checkBoxPhone = createCheckBox(R.id.checkBoxPhone);


checkBoxAdress = createCheckBox(R.id.checkBoxAdress);
```

I want to get their values 0 or 1 if some of the checkboxes are checked or not , and when i got their values i want to put them into a array. My checkboxes are inside a array

`ArrayList<CheckBox> boxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();`

Comment: could you add the code where you use this?

Comment: my code is very long.I use this array to send him to a API. The array must content boolean values of all checkboxes.

Comment: I'm lost with what you are asking you need to improve your question some more

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the arraylist and get the value. Something like

```
for (int i = 0; i<boxes.size(); i++){
    CheckBox cb = boxes.get(i);
    if (cb.isChecked()){
      System.out.println("checked");
      //from here you can populate you array
    }else{
      System.out.println("not checked");
      //from here you can populate you array
    }
}
```

======= Edit after the comment =======

```
public class CheckBoxStatus{

    CheckBox cb;
    boolean blnIsChecked;

    public CheckBoxStatus(CheckBox cb, boolean blnIsChecked){
      this.cb = cb;
      this.blnIsChecked = blnIsChecked;
    }

    public CheckBox getCheckbox(){
       return this.cb;
    }

    public boolean getStatus(){
       return this.blnIsChecked;
    }

    public boolean setStatus(boolean blnIsChecked){
        this.blnIsChecked = blnIsChecked;
    }

}

//Now in your code instead of ArrayList<CheckBox>, use ArrayList<CheckBoxStatus>

ArrayList<CheckBoxStatus> alCBS = new ArrayList<CheckBoxStatus>();
CheckBoxStatus cbs = new CheckBoxStatus(<checkbox instance>, false); //pass false as default value;
alCBS.add(cbs);

//Modified loop
for (int i = 0; i<boxes.size(); i++){
  CheckBox cb = boxes.get(i);
  CheckBoxStatus cbs = new CheckBoxStatus(cb, cb.isChecked());
  boxes.set(i, cbs);
}
```

Comment: yea but i want to get there boolean values and put them in the same array.I use this array to send it to a API with all boolean values of my checkboxes :)

Comment: then you need to create a POJO class. Let me update my answer and give you some hint.